Sending preformatted EML file through Python's SMTPLIB when recipient is already in the EML file content
I've got a process that creates a couple of individual emails and stores each in a separate EML file. The EML file already containt the recipient. The head of the files look like this:
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Unsent: 1
To: =?utf-8?B?PHBodW5AZ214LmNoPg==?=
Subject: =?utf-8?B?TWl0Z2xpZWRlcmJlaXRyYWc=?=
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="Am_iolBmiLoblxpmqITPVQ"

--Am_iolBmiLoblxpmqITPVQ
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="mTzYHMqN9apRVLol1SFmNg"
...

Up to now, I copied those EML file to the draft folder in thunderbird, opened each one, and just clicked on send. The number of mails will in crease, so I'm looking for an autoamted process.
Note that I don't have access to the code which creates the EML files, so I cannot modify it to send them directly.
I want to send all those EML files using some Python code. The code shall pickup each EML file in a directory and send it to an SMPT server. I had a look at Python's smtplib package, but is seems the sendmail() function always expects the receiver as second argument.
I could extract the TO: address from each file before handing over to sendmail(), but I'd like to avoid this. Is there a way?
